# Questions that ask many duplicates

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500179/share-point-where-to-start) contains many questions but also all of those questions have been asked separately (or together) by other users. So it's essentially a multi-dupe question.

What to do when only one question can be chosen as an "exact duplicate"? Is it better to write a multi-dupe answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you'd post a comment that outlines all of the different duplicates, and then vote to close based on the one that is most similar to the question.

If a comment isn't big enough to fit all of the duplicates, or if you want to describe each duplicate, a community wiki answer would be alright, too, as well as the vote to close.

Once the question is closed, if you think an important duplicate link has been left out, you might want to edit it back into the possible duplicates list.

Comment: Community wiki answer is a good idea, never thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

I would vote to close as an exact duplicate of whatever you feel is the "best" question that it is a duplicate of. I would also provide a comment or an answer (which personally I would make community wiki) that kindly points in the direction of the other relevant questions.

Comment: I usually do the comment but in this case there are many!

Comment: If there are a lot, then I would probably go with a CW answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, questions that have multiple questions in the question should probably have each question separated into its own question. That just makes it easier for everyone all around especially when it comes to answering and voting. How do you handle it if you answer part correct and part wrong, etc. etc.

If the question has multiple duplicates, close it as a duplicate and then you (or whoever has proper privileges) can edit the post to contain the links that it dupes. Also, if it gets closed with multiple votes going to multiple questions, all of those questions will be posted at the top automatically as well.

Comment: It's up to the OP to separate the questions right? If I did it they'd show up as me asking them.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the question was closed and I edited it with all of the duplicates I could find. (Interesting that a lot of those were duplicates of each other, but hey!)

In the future I'll post a comment if there are one or two duplicates and leave a community wiki answer if there are more than that. Thanks for the advice.